# Getting 403 Forbidden from Artifact Registry While Deploying a Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-artifact-registry

## What I Want to Do

I have published my private npm package onto Artifact Registry, and the diagram below is what I'm trying to do.

[image: diagram]

Basically I want to use the private package from both `project-staging` and `project-production`. So my `package.json` looks something like:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@<scope>/private_package": "^1.0.0",
},
```

## What I Did

### Giving Permission to Cloud Build Service Account

I gave `artifactregistry.reader` permission to both `<project-staging_id>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` and `<project-production_id>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` under IAM menu in `project-common`.

### `.npmrc` Preparation

```bash
cd path/to/project_directory

gcloud artifacts print-settings npm \
    --project=project-common \
    --repository=private_package \
    --location=<location> \
    --scope=@<scope>

vim .npmrc
# => add the output of above gcloud command

npx google-artifactregistry-auth .npmrc
```

### deploy

```bash
gcloud config configurations activate project-staging

gcloud functions deploy <function_name> --gen2 --region=<region> --trigger-http --runtime=nodejs16 --entry-point=<entry_point>
```

This gives me the following error.

```bash
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://<URL>.tgz - Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "<resource_name>" (or it may not exist)
```

I don't know why I'm getting this even though
`<project-staging_id>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` has `artifactregistry.reader` permission.
Is there anything else I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because I had added `.npmrc` to `.gcloudignore`. Removing `.npmrc` from `.gcloudignore` made it work. Silly mistake.
I'm going to try [Automate and protect your Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/using-private-repo-artifact-registry-google-cloud-functions?hl=en) as a next step, but for now my problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally the role `roles/artifactregistry.reader` is sufficient to download packages from the repo on `project_common`.

If `project_staging` and `project_production` have the `roles/artifactregistry.reader` on `project_common` it should work.

The `roles/artifactregistry.reader` role contains the following permissions :

```
artifactregistry.repositories.list
artifactregistry.repositories.get
artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts
artifactregistry.files.list
artifactregistry.files.get
artifactregistry.packages.list
artifactregistry.packages.listTagBindings
artifactregistry.repositories.listEffectiveTags
artifactregistry.packages.list
artifactregistry.tags.list
artifactregistry.tags.get
artifactregistry.versions.list
artifactregistry.versions.get
artifactregistry.locations.list
artifactregistry.locations.get
```

Please check again your configuration and the identity that performs the failed action.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm pretty sure that I have the correct permission to the correct service account...